# UIScreenEdgePanGesture in Xamarin Crashes with error:critical: Stacktrace:

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to add UIScreenEdgePanGesture in Xamarin for iOS. But it crashes. I am using following code

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer rightEdgeGesture = new UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer (HandleRightEdgeGesture);          
                rightEdgeGesture.Edges = UIRectEdge.Right;
                View.AddGestureRecognizer (rightEdgeGesture);
```

and also handle action

```
public void HandleRightEdgeGesture(UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer recognizer){
        Console.WriteLine("Screen to right");
     }
```

Please help me if I am writing any wrong syntax.